# Logging a Clojure Agent

Tags: logging, clojure

I am using [agents](https://clojure.org/reference/agents) to setup a processing chain. I also want to have a logger keep track of what's happened.  The entire code is here.

I can see that the `:charlie` msg is processed and even goes to the  `log` function as it is printed... **after** being "sent" to be "conj'ed" to the logger agent.

Why does charlie never show up in my `@logger`?

```
(def logger (agent []))  ;; logger to keep track of what's done

(defn log [msg]
  (send logger conj msg)  ;; charlie's msg is NOT conj'ed
  (println "logged" msg)) ;; but charilies msg IS printed

(defn create-relay [coll]
  (reduce (comp agent vector) nil (reverse coll)))  ;; see partial answer below

(defn relay-msg [next-agent prev-msg]
  (if (nil? next-agent)
    (log "finished relay")
    (let [new-msg (str prev-msg (second next-agent))]
      ;; do something interesting with new-msg then:
      (log new-msg)
      ;; go do the next thing
      (send (first next-agent) relay-msg new-msg))))

(send (create-relay [:alice :bob :charlie]) relay-msg "hello")
(. java.lang.Thread sleep 5000)
(prn @logger)
```

output:

```
logged hello:alice
logged hello:alice:bob
logged hello:alice:bob:charlie
["hello:alice" "hello:alice:bob"]
;; expected last line to be:
;; ["hello:alice" "hello:alice:bob" "hello:alice:bob:charlie"]
```

**Partial Answer**
I have found how to make it work but I'm still looking to "accept" an answer that explains where the error went to hide from me.

The printing is a side effect.  The agent is "consistent" state (whatever that means).  After "logging" charlie, the next line calls "send to nil" in this line:

```
(send (first next-agent) relay-msg new-msg) ;; =>(first next-agent) is nil
```

Seems like it should be a `NullPointerException` but it never shows up.  Swallowed because it's in another thread???

fixed with the following hard-to-grok change:

```
(reduce (comp agent vector) nil (reverse coll))
;; => change to =>
(reduce (comp agent vector) (agent nil) (reverse coll))
```

Why silent on the error?
And is it right that the `@logging` got rolled back?
What if there were other items "conj'ed" to `logging` after the rollback?

I have "working" code but I'm still lost on proper behavior here.  "Un"-logging something sounds scary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found on the [Clojure reference page for Agents](https://clojure.org/reference/agents):

> 5. If during the function execution any other dispatches are made (directly or indirectly), they will be held until after the state of the Agent has been changed.

"Other dispatches" here means, in essence, calls to `send`.  So when `relay-msg` is executed for a particular agent, all the calls to `send` are queued until `relay-msg` returns the new state of the agent.  In the case of `:alice` and `:bob`, the queued `send`s are then dispatched once the agent's state is updated.

But since `relay-msg` on `:charlie` throws a `NullPointerException`, the agent for `:charlie` is put into an error state and the queued `send`s (including the one in the call to `log`) are discarded.

> Seems like it should be a NullPointerException but it never shows up. Swallowed because it's in another thread???

Sort of.  In actuality, exceptions are encapsulated by the agent dispatch mechanism.  If the function passed to `send` throws an exception, it is caught and the agent is put into an error state.  The exception is stored on the agent, and can be accessed via [`agent-error`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/agent-error).  (Also, subsequent calls to `send` on a failed agent throw the original exception.)